# Hibernate select distinct return only id

Tags: hibernate, distinct, hibernate-criteria

```
class Cat {
    long id;
    String name;
    int age
}

List<Cat> results = (List<Cat>) session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")) )
    )
    .list();
```

It works perfectly without set projection, but has duplicates by id.
When we add set projection, the query return only a list if ids(1, 2, 3).

How to change to return a list of cats and non duplicate id?

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12437

Comment: What is that `Cat` object contains?

Comment: class Cat {
    long id;
    String name;
    int age
}

Comment: change return type to `List<Cat> results`

Comment: it is the same :(

Comment: Replace your code with `Criteria obj =  session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")) )
    );
 
List<Cats> result = criteria.list();`

Comment: it is the same, i tryed already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167426/discussion-between-arvind-katte-and-combo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` on the criteria object. But it is implemented not in a database side - it's programically filtered (after the DB query is fired, Hibernate filters for distinct rows).

Another better option is to use `setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Cat.class))` and you need to use projection with distinct as above and also have projection on all the properties that you want to populate in the Cat entity. This uses distinct keyword in the SQL query and so filtering happens in the DB)

You can go through this [hibernate forum - select distinct entities using Criteria](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=941669) for an example and more information on the related discussion.

Comment: >also have projection on all the properties that you want to populate in the Cat entity
I need all fields, is there a way to populate not manually?

Comment: In the same hibernate forum link above, you will find an approach to dynamically populate all fields it the projections. It talks of using `String[] properties = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(User.class).getPropertyNames();` and then subsequently use a for look on the `properties` with `list.add(Projections.property(properties[i]), properties[i]`